# Java Map get not working even after overriding hashcode and equals

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a custom Key Object defined as such.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Key implements Serializable {

    private String key; //JSON
    private LocalDateTime expiry;
    private long cacheId;
    private LocalDateTime accessed;

    public Key(Long cacheId, String key, LocalDateTime expiry) {
        this.key = key;
        this.expiry = expiry;
        this.cacheId = cacheId;
        this.accessed = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

The ***key*** attribute inside **Key** usually contains JSON strings.
The *hashcode* and *equals* are overridden as

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Key key1 = (Key) o;
        return cacheId == key1.cacheId && key.equals(key1.key);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(cacheId, key);
    }
```

In another place I have a ***treeMap*** defined as **private Map<Key, Object> map;**

When I try to call map.get() using an existing Key (Key with matching cacheId and string key value), I don't get the desired value back, even though while I'm debugging the issue I can see that the map contains the value with a Key with the matching cacheId and string key value.

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the example code that works not as it should?

Comment: `TreeMap` uses neither `hashCode` nor `equals`. You’ll have to show how you construct your `TreeMap` as your `Key` isn’t `Comparable`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider  I don't believe the Key object has to implement the Comparable interface since one can pass a comparator as an argument to `TreeMap`.

Comment: @WJS that’s _exactly_ my point, no? I specifically ask to see the construction _becuase_ `Key` isn’t `Comparable`!

Comment: Boris is right actually. Found the problem, treemap and hashmap both use hashcode of the key to find the bucket inside the map where the key belongs. After that, hashmap uses equals on the key to find it inside the specified bucket, while treeMap uses compare to. My key object did not extend the comparable interface, hence treeMap wasn't able to find it.